# Make calls using home phone and raspberry by dialling a number using my existing POTs line

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, phone-call, ivr

Connect a small board computer (like raspberry) between POTS and my home phone to configure it to copy the number I am dialling on my phone and call another number (which i have for a service) instead and put the copied number in IVR of that call.

I am Java & Linux developer just needed some advice on how to startup with this project.